# Get first ever windows eventlog entry using EventLogQuery

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I'm trying to get the first eventlog entry using C# `EventLogQuery` 
but I can't seem to find the appropriate query..

```
string queryString = "*[System[(EventId= 1)]]";
string queryString = "*[System[(InstanceId = 1)]]";
string queryString = "*[System[(RecordNumber= 1)]]";

EventRecord eventRecord;
EventLogQuery query = new EventLogQuery(LOG_SYSTEM, PathType.LogName, queryString);
EventLogReader reader = new EventLogReader(query);

eventRecord = reader.ReadEvent();

return eventRecord;
```

all result in null..

This works but is rather slow:

```
var log = EventLog.GetEventLogs(Environment.MachineName);
var systemLog = log.Single(l => l.Log == "System");
var firstEntry = systemLog.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().OrderBy(l => l.InstanceId).First();
```

So I'm looking for the correct query for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the query is **case-sensitive**...

This simply works and is blazing fast!

```
string queryString = "*[System[(EventID = 1)]]";
```

Comment: This only works until the event log wraps, and the event associated with Event ID 1 gets automatically deleted. I am trying to find a solution that does not rely on the EventID field. Anyone have any ideas?